# How can i color only the numbers of each line n a richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i want to do is to color in Red only the numbers in the richTextBox2.
But it's coloring in red the whole text in the richTextBox2.

```
public static class RichTextBoxExtensions
    {
        public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
        {
            box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;

            box.SelectionColor = color;
            box.AppendText(text);
            box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
        }
    }
```

In the constructor:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test\new 2.txt");
richTextBox1.Text = text;
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Lines;
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    string tt = (i + 1).ToString();
    RichTextBoxExtensions.AppendText(richTextBox2, tt, Color.Red);
    lines[i] = tt + " " + lines[i];
}
richTextBox2.Lines = lines;
```

This is the original code before trying to color the numbers.

```
string[]  lines = richTextBox2.Lines;

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    lines[i] = (i+1) + " " + lines[i];
}
richTextBox2.Lines = lines;
```

Comment: You would have to parse your "text" variable since it sounds like it starts with a number and then has text.  What separates the number from the text?

Comment: @LarsTech I added now to my question the original code before trying to color the numbers how i added the numbers. This line separates the number from the text: lines[i] = (i+1) + " " + lines[i];

Comment: Where is it trying to highlight a specific part of a line? It looks like it will always color all text because that is what you are selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the extension method to append the text but only color the numbers, then you just need to first add the text, one character at a time, scan each character to see if it's numeric, and if it is, select it and color it:

```
public static class Extenstions
{
    public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, Color color)
    {
        // Append the text, but color only the numbers
        foreach (char character in text)
        {
            box.AppendText(character.ToString());

            if (char.IsNumber(character))
            {
                box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength - 1;
                box.SelectionLength = 1;
                box.SelectionColor = color;
                box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
                box.SelectionColor = box.ForeColor;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution and i did: for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                lines[i] = (i + 1) + " " + lines[i];
                Extenstions.AppendText(richTextBox2, lines[i], Color.Red);
            }
            richTextBox2.Lines = lines; but it keep coloring the whole text. Can you show me please also how also to use the Extenstions ?

Comment: If you add the above extensions method, and then call `richTextBox1.AppendText("This contains 1 number", Color.Red);` then the `1` in the text will be colored red and the rest should be black. At least on my machine